# I can't get phone number from user use firebase flutter

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, firebase-authentication, gmail

```
final GoogleSignInAccount? googleUser = await googleSignIn.signIn();
      if (googleUser == null) return;
      _user = googleUser;

      final googleAuth = await googleUser.authentication;

      final OAuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(
        accessToken: googleAuth.accessToken,
        idToken: googleAuth.idToken,
      );

      final UserCredential userCredential = await _auth.signInWithCredential(credential);

      final idToken = await userCredential.user!.getIdToken();
      print(" id token:$idToken");

      final user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!;
      final Map<String, dynamic> data = {
        'uid': idToken,
        'email': user.email,
        'name': user.displayName,
        'avatar': user.photoURL,
        'phone': user.phoneNumber ?? "",
      };
      print("data:"
          + ' email: ' + user.email!
          + ', name: ' + user.displayName!
          + ', avatar: ' + user.photoURL!
          + ', phone: ' + user.phoneNumber!
      );
```

Just only phoneNumber is null

`Null check operator used on a null value`

I added a phone number to my gmail but my gmail already has a previous phone number. I also created a new gmail account with SMS confirmation of my phone number to the new gmail but it still comes out null. I do not know what to do.

Answer (score 0):

Google do not share users phone number for signIn.

Comment: sohow i can get phone number. Is there no other way? 
Thank you

Comment: you can ask user for his mobile no.